# Find index of array inside *another* array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var people = {};

people.manager = [12,13,14]

people.cashier = [6,7,8]
```

The above is an example of code that I am doing. It is not about "managers" or anything but I made this up to make it more easy to answer.

My question is that: how do I find a certain 'key' (apparently it is not called 'index') of `people`?

For example, a normal array lets me do `people.manager[2]` to get that index (which is `14`).

**EDIT:** I changed index to key because it might make more sense.

Comment: What error do you get when you to `people.manager[2]`?

Comment: @jsve read again, there's no error there, it yields 14 like he said.

Comment: @RUJordan Wow. I should go to bed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @jsve It works, but only for the "inside arrays" like manager and cashier. But doing [2] for the "people array" returns as "undefined"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @BorgonAtoE!  Your questions will always be more understandable to others if you include what you've tried already and the error output you received.  In this case, you would include your comment about returning "undefined" in the actual question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With objects, you can use bracket notation to try and pull a key (not index) out.

So, you could do:

```
var key = "manager";
people[key][2]; //14
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, that is almost exactly what I wanted to know, but what if there are many "keys" and it would be very inefficient to make a variable for all of them?

Comment: @BorgonAtoE that's tricky, because with arrays, they use numeric indices which are easy to loop over. For objects, if you want to iterate it, you can use a `for (x in people)` loop which iterates over  they keys -- but it's not good for sorting.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect! It might not seem like a very good idea to use for in loops but whatever: for (var x in people) { alert(x); }